# I want to create module that retrieve all controllers within "api" namespace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to create module that retrieve all controllers within "api" namespace but this code do not include controllers from gem, can you help me to refactor this code and retrieve controllers from gem too.

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

module ApiControllers
  mattr_accessor :list

  def list
    return @list if @list

    @list = Rails.application.routes.set.anchored_routes.map(&:defaults).filter_map do |route|
      if route[:controller].start_with?('api/')
        "#{route[:controller].camelize}Controller"
      end
    end
  end

  module_function :list
end
```

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate on why you need this list and add an example in which your code doesn't work as expected?

Comment: Gems don't have to use Rails' routing or Rails style controllers at all. They can use Rack to handle incoming requests. What are the gems you are interested in?

Comment: I'm curious why you need this, anyway I think the easiest way to go here is to look into $LOAD_PATH https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html. Once your app boots your files and constans defined in them are loaded to your load Path so you can read them from there.

Comment: I have Admin UI filter "filter :controller, as: :select, collection: proc { ApiControllers.list }, input_html: { class: :chosen }" and inside this filter I want to display all controllers name within the "API" namespace

Comment: you can see usage of this module ApiControllers within this repo https://github.com/yeti-switch/yeti-web

-
https://github.com/search?q=repo%3Ayeti-switch%2Fyeti-web+ApiControllers&type=code